# Mysql using join and in array match

Tags: mysql, arrays

Am trying to select all `student` from table and join it with `staff` table where the student `current_class` is in array list of `staff` `staff_classes`.
I have tried below query but it only show one record when i have more than one record in selected staff `staff_classes` . Please any idea how to get this working.

school_staffs

```
staff_id      | staff_classes   | staff_name
--------------|-----------------|---------------------------
peter123      | A,B             | Peter
fara123       | A               | Fara
```

students

```
student_id     |  current_class    | student_name
---------------|-------------------|----------------
john123        | A                 |  John
paul123        | A                 | Paul
dev123         | B                 | Dev
heg123         | C                 | Heg
mag123         | C                 | Mag
```

my current attempt.
What am actually trying to do below is to list all students that is under staffs that manage `A` and `B` class.

```
SELECT st.student_name, st.student_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(st.student_id ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(st.current_class , 'A,B'))
FROM students AS st
JOIN school_staffs AS stf ON FIND_IN_SET(st.current_class , 'A,B') > 0
GROUP BY st.current_class
```

Let assume that the current logged in staff is `peter123` and the `staff_classes` is `A,B`

Expected Result for above query is :-

```
student_id     |  current_class    | student_name
---------------|-------------------|---------------------------
john123        | A                 |  John
paul123        | A                 | Paul
dev123         | B                 | Dev
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output?  Note that storing CSV like this is not ideal database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `student_id` in `group_by` as well.

```
SELECT s.*, ss.staff_name FROM `students` AS s, `school_staffs` AS ss
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(s.current_class, ss.staff_classes)
GROUP BY s.current_class, s.student_id;
```

> Note : Make sure `staff_classes` column contains comma separated values for multiple. It is okay for single value.

[MySql Fiddle](https://paiza.io/projects/qNc64brTzRpyXk1xe45HaA?language=mysql).